Where is my Google Maps timeline data stored on my Android phone?
Recently, Google decided to remove Google Maps "timeline" from their servers and store at the end user's device; my Android phone in my case.
I completed this conversion. And still, I do have backup to cloud (i.e., Google servers) on; but I want to see the actual files the data is stored on my phone.
I connected my phone to a computer and searched for all (most) locations under Internal shared storage. The obvious destination for such data is /Android/data/com.google.android.apps.maps/; but I found nothing relevant here.
Does anybody know the exact (directory) location on the end user's device where the Google Maps "timeline" data is stored?

I also have this question, though for iOS. (I'm assuming the answers will be similar.) I lost the data after the migration to my phone; it seems like it's not part of iCloud backups? Unless I'm just looking in the wrong place. Hopefully someone shares an answer with us.

The file is likely encrypted; thus, you cannot find it in the phone folder. You cannot get the timeline history from Google Takeout (accessible from Google Maps) since the data is no longer there.
The answer is in the Phone Settings instead of the Google Maps application (at least on Samsung Phones—possibly other Android Phones). Go to Settings—Location—Timeline—Export Timeline Data. You will need to define the target directory and select the Download folder. You will get Timeline.JSON in the Download folder.
It is up to you to proceed this file but you can take a peek using Notepad.

Maybe because my timeline hasn't been downgraded to be on my phone only yet, but this option is not available on my Oneplus 4 Lite.
I wonder if it is possible for some app to download this data (when the service has degraded to be on the phone) so it can be downloaded to a server of my own choice to make it available on the PC again.
